# Updating Flex Air Mobile in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I am trying to develop an app for Iphone using Flash Builder / Flex Mobile. When i submitted to the app store it was rejected due to an invalid binary. I tracked this down to needing to update the Air SDK to 3.7.

To update I have tried various methods:
1) Download the latest version of Flex SDK (4.6) from Adobe site
2) Download the latest non beta version of Air (3.7) from Adobe site
3) Using a PC (rather than MAC) i then merged the folders together and then transferred back to the MAC.

First time round Flash Builder threw an error on TabbedViewNavigationApplication i think that this was due to not havng the mobile.swc and mobilecomponents.swc so i added these in to the compiler, this error then disappeared but when the app ran it just produced a blank white screen.

When i try to create a new mobile flex Tabbed Application, flash builder will not create it, it just stays on the final page of the wizard. If i add the mobile.swc and mobilecomponents then it creates the app but still doesn’t run correctly (white screen or Process terminated unexpectedly). This sort of implies that I have done something wrong as it doesn’t know it’s a flex mobile app.

I think it has upgraded air to 3.7 as the namespace in the xml file has 3.7 in it, I have also made sure to add the –sef-verson=20 in the compiler.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong, am using the wrong SDKs etc,  I want to achieve the following:

Flash Builder 4.7 running Flex 4.6 with Air 3.7

Any help gratefully received.
Thanks Toby

Answer (score 1):

Now sorted in case anybody else has problems:

1) Use the 4.6 Flex SDK that came with FLash Builder - dont try and download an new one
2) Make sure you download the AIR 3.7 update for Flex (not the normal update)
3) Copy 3.7 Update over the flex 4.6 directory (take a backup) and dont use a MAC as it will delete files.
4) When you have updated the directory make sure to change the namespace
5) Make sure to add -swf-version=20 to the compile option.

Its actually very simple - but also very easy to completly screw up